# VS Code で CSS の編集時に表示される波線を非表示にしたい

Tags: css, vscode

VS Codeの黄色の波線を非表示にする方法が知りたいです。

[image]

Comment: これは「スタイルシートの中身を空にするな」という警告が出ている状態でしょうか。

Comment: 英語版SOでの回答とコメントが参考になるかもしれません。 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32464333/2322778

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます！分かりましたので、回答としてあげさせていただきます。

Comment: @htb はい！そのとおりです！

Answer (score 2):

設定に該当項目がありました！
→「ignore」

https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1807/03/news025.html

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]